# DB schema problem

Tags: database-design

I have tables

- USERS,
- CLUBS (`id, creator_id, name, description`)
- MONOPOLY (`id, results`)
- RISK (`id, results, risk_specific_field`)

Relations are:

- `USERS n:n CLUBS` // I have weak entity between them
- `CLUBS 1:n MONOPOLY`
- `CLUBS 1:n RISK`

Users create clubs of friends and invite them to that club to play different games (Monopoly, RIsk).

If the game is e.g. monopoly then there should be relation between `Game` and `Monopoly` table. I thought creating weak entities between `Games/Monopoly` and `Games/Risk` which would work, but I am confused whether this approach is good because weak entities are used to break N:N relations and these ones are 1:n (one game relates to 1 row of `Monopoly` table and `Monopoly` to N rows of `Game` table). Also this approach would allow our app to add new types of games with their own tables etc.

If the only type of game was `Monopoly` I would add field **id_monopoly** in my `Games` table and that would be it, but since my app has `Risk` also I can't do it this way.

Hell, I hope I was clear about what concerns me here :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is polymorphic associations.

Instead of adding just `id_monopoly`, you would generalize it and add two fields, such as:

`id_game`, `type_game` - where `id_game` is either a "foreign key" to monopoly or to risk and `type_game` is either "monopoly" or "risk".

The catch here is that you will need some application logic to look up the ids in the proper table, which can get complicated, but hope this helps in your case.

Comment: Yep, you got it right :) 
So, you're suggesting two foreign keys...
This approach would defenitely work, but is it the right solution? I mean, I've never seen a case like this so I wouldn't know :/

Comment: Yes, this is a common solution. For a rails guide that uses the same concept, you can see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations I think it is not used very often, because of the required logic, but if you want a setup like you described, this is the way to do it. If you can control it though, I'd recommend to consider changing your requirements that a polymorphic association is not needed.